# Importing Macros doesn't work

Tags: templating, craft3

I'm trying to upgrade my website to Craft 3, so I've imported all template files and installed the necessary plugins, but I can't deal with one error.

I've got a template named `_layout.twig`, and the first line used to import macros from other file called `_helpers.twig`. For some reason this doesn't work on Craft 3 - I checked in [Twig documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html#importing-macros) and it seems that everything is correct. I reviewed the changes in Craft 3 but didn't find anything related there. Running Craft 3.3 with Twig 2.11.3.

**_layout.twig**

```
{% import '_common/_helpers' as helpers %}
{{ helpers }}
```

**Error**

> Twig Runtime Error – Twig\Error\RuntimeError
>   Variable "helpers" does not exist.
>
> in /craft3/templates/_layout.twig at line 2

Any ideas what can be the issue here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to reference a macro name inside of your `_common/_helpers` file.

For example:

```
{{ helpers.input('username') }}
```

That would output a macro called `input`:

```
{% macro input(name, value, type = "text", size = 20) %}
    <input type="{{ type }}" name="{{ name }}" value="{{ value|e }}" size="{{ size }}" />
{% endmacro %}
```